# hibernate - createCriteria or createAlias?

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, createcriteria

If I want to search those students who take class "Math" and "John" is his group:

shoud I use createCriteria or createAlias?

```
Criteria:

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
Criteria subquery1 = criteria.createCriteria("courses", course).add(Restrictions.eq(course.name, "Math"));
Criteria subquery2 = criteria.createCriteria("group", student).add(Restrictions.eq(student.name, "John"));
```

how to put subquery1 and subquery2 together with initial criteria?

```
Alias:

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class).
createAlias("courses", course).add(Restrictions.eq(course.name, "Math")).
createCriteria("group", student).add(Restrictions.eq(student.name, "John"));
```

When to use createCriteria and when createAlias? I think the boath are the same...

Comment: I'm not sure if this was a Java/Hibernate or a C#/NHibernate question, so have answered for both.

Comment: there are subtle differences between CreateCriteria and CreateAlias, each has a purpose.
Check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899079/nhibernate-createcriteria-vs-createalias/921042#921042

This is actually a duplicate question

Answer (score 25, accepted):

CreateAlias and CreateCriteria are **identical** in the current versions of Hibernate and NHibernate. The only difference being that CreateCriteria has 2 additional overloads without the alias parameter.

Presumably they were different in a older version, but any differences are long gone.

An alias can be defined in terms of another alias, so your first example can be written as:

```
// Java
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class)
    .createAlias("courses", "course")
    .createAlias("course.group", "student")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("course.name", "Math"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("student.name", "John"));

// C#
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Student>()
    .CreateAlias("Courses", "course")
    .CreateAlias("course.Group", "student")
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("course.Name", "Math"))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("student.Name", "John"));
```

Comment: sorry didn't tell you that i am using nhibernate for C#. So if i undesrtand correctly createAlias is the same as createCriteria, but createCriteria can use different join but createAlias can only use inner join. Am i right?

Comment: @senzacionale JoinType parameter is available via both method names.

Comment: they are not the same thing
note that CreateCriteria exposes an ICriteria object which can be manipulated besides the "root" ICriteria object
check my answer at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899079/nhibernate-createcriteria-vs-createalias/921042#921042

Comment: This answer is simply incorrect. Depending which method you use it has different results: @sorrymissjackson response.

Answer (score 22):

Adding to xavierzhoa's answer:

There is actually quite a big difference between the two methods which you will notice if you chain `Criteria` methods. You will continue to work on the original `Criteria` object when using `createAlias`, whereas you work on a more nested scope when using `createCriteria`.

Consider this:

```
    Criteria c = getSession()
      .createCriteria(YourEntity.class)
      .createCriteria("someMember", "s")
      .add(Restrictions.eq("name", someArgument));  // checks YourEntity.someMember.name
```

versus

```
    Criteria c = getSession()
      .createCriteria(YourEntity.class)
      .createAlias("someMember", "s")
      .add(Restrictions.eq("name", someArgument));  // checks  YourEntity.name
```

However, if you always assign and use an alias you will be able to work around the difference. Like:

```
    Criteria c = getSession()
      .createCriteria(YourEntity.class, "y")
      .createAlias("someMember", "s")
      .add(Restrictions.eq("y.name", someArgument));  // no more confusion
```

Comment: yeah very usefull

Answer (score 14):

Please refer to the following source code from the Hibernate

```
public Criteria createCriteria(String associationPath, String alias, int joinType) {
    return new Subcriteria( this, associationPath, alias, joinType );
}


public Criteria createAlias(String associationPath, String alias, int joinType) {
    new Subcriteria( this, associationPath, alias, joinType );
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria criteria = (Criteria)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(BillEntity.class)
        .createAlias("worksEntity", "worksEntity" ,JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
```

instead of writing (Jointype) use the import file as

```
(org.hibernate.sql.JoinType..LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
```