# Hibernate criteria API equals method

Tags: hibernate

I have used hibernate reverse engineering to generate my model and Dao classes
i am using hibernate criteria API to retrive values from database

```
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(
            "propert1.propert2.StateId", 1));
```

i am getting the following exception

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: propert1.propert2.StateId of: com.packagename.

Has any body got the clue why is this happening.(create criteria has the class which has property1 and class of propert1 have propert2 )

Comment: Capital "S"? By convention Java bean property names begin with a small letter (i.e. `getName` => Property name is `name`).

Comment: yes i have changed it here, but in my class these are properly named because these classes are generated through hibernate  reverse engineering, so that is not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked for me

```
Criteria criteria = session
            .createCriteria(MyClass.class);
criteria = criteria.createCriteria("propert1").createCriteria("propert2").add(Restrictions.eq("stateId", 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining aliases should do it

```
criteria.createAlias("propert1","pr1")
    .createAlias("pr1.propert2","pr2")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("pr2.StateId", 1));
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply i have tried something like this criteria = criteria.createCriteria("propert1").createCriteria("propert2").add(Restrictions.eq("stateId", 1)); and it worked for me. i will try it ur way also.

Comment: @curious : Both approaches are almost identical. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347359/hibernate-createcriteria-or-createalias and alike, if you are really "curious" ;)

Comment: @curious : Also, would help someone if you update your question with your solution!

Comment: i have tried ur way but i got the following exception  org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: stateId of: Myclass