# Regex Hibernate alias

Tags: java, regex, hibernate

How is it to use an alias in hibernate in a sqlRestriction .. 
Here is my code but it does not work, it does not recognize "emet" and "dest" as aliases

```
criteria.createAlias("personne", "emet", JoinFragment.INNER_JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("destinataire", "dest", JoinFragment.INNER_JOIN)
        .createCriteria("fichier")
        .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("({alias}.codic SIMILAR TO 'U[AB0-9]{4}' and emet.cod = 'ERF') OR (emet.codic SIMILAR TO '[^U]%' and dest.codic like 'AA%') OR (emet.codic SIMILAR TO 'U[AB0-9]{4}' and {dest}.codic SIMILAR TO '[^U]%')"));
```

Comment: can you please add  more code snippet for better understating of what are you doing!!!!

Comment: Ok . I want use the alias "emet" and "dest" in my Restrictions.sqlRestriction but I don't khow how to do it

Comment: So I want translate this sql in hibernate `select *
from 
 pfr.message m
 inner join pfr.partenaire emet on m.idEmet=emet.idPart
 inner join pfr.partenaire dest2_ on m.idDest=dest.idPart
where  emet.codic SIMILAR TO 'U[AB0-9]{4}' and dest2_.codic = 'U0000'`

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347359/hibernate-createcriteria-or-createalias