# SQL join QUERY to Nhibernate icriteria conversion

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I am basically new to Nhibernate and I am facing problems in converting this query to NHibernate ICriteria interface:

```
SELECT Batch, 
       FkDegreeID,
       CourseTitle
  FROM JinnahCourseMapping
  JOIN JinnahCourse ON JinnahCourseMapping.FkCourseID = JinnahCourse.ID
 WHERE JinnahCourseMapping.FkDegreeID = 196608 
   AND JinnahCourseMapping.Batch = '2007';
```

I can't seem to find any solid answer to the problem, I'm hoping someone will be able to help me here :(

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to convert this to ICriteria and not HQL or LINQ? Which version of NHibernate are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql code seems to be quite straightforward. What kind of problem do you have? Here is a similar question that could help you: [NHibernate - CreateCriteria vs CreateAlias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899079/nhibernate-createcriteria-vs-createalias).