# NHibernate - selecting data from referenced objects (traversing many-to-one relationship) in a query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria

i want to build a query that will select some columns from a joined table (many to one relationship in my data model).

```
var q = ses.QueryOver<Task>().Select(x => x.Id, x => x.CreatedDate, x => x.AssigneeGroup.Name, x => x.AssigneeGroup.IsProcessGroup);
```

Here i'm retrieving properties from AssigneeGroup which is a reference to another table, specified in my mapping. But when I try to run this query I get

> Exception: could not resolve property: AssigneeGroup.Name of: Task

So it looks like NHibernate is not able to follow relations defined in my mapping and doesn't know that in order to resolve AssigneeGroup.Name we should do a join from 'Task' to 'Groups' table and retrieve Group.Name column. 
So, my question is, how to build such queries? I have this expression: x => x.AssigneeGroup.Name, how to convert it to proper Criteria, Projections and Aliases? Or is there a way to do this automatically? It should be possible because NHibernate has all the information...

Comment: If you wrote this as a Criteria query, you could use the `SetFetchMode` method with a Join, and you'd prolly be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query need association and  should look like this:

```
// firstly we need to get an alias for "AssigneeGroup", to be used later
AssigneeGroup assigneeGroup = null;

var q = ses
    .QueryOver<Task>()
    // now we will join the alias
    .JoinAlias(x => x.AssigneeGroup, () => assigneeGroup) 
    .Select(x => x.Id
          , x => x.CreatedDate

          // instead of these
          // , x => x.AssigneeGroup.Name
          // , x => x.AssigneeGroup.IsProcessGroup

          // use alias for SELECT/projection (i.e. ignore "x", use assigneeGroup)
          , x => assigneeGroup.Name
          , x => assigneeGroup.IsProcessGroup
     );
```

More and interesting reading:

- [NHibernate - CreateCriteria vs CreateAlias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899079/), to get more understanding when to use `JoinAlias` *(CreateAlias)* and when `JoinQueryOver` *(CreateCriteria)*
- `Criteria` API for: [15.4. Associations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-associations)
- `QueryOver` API for [16.4. Associations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-associations)

Comment: This is probably the correct answer. Unfortunately, NHIbernate is not able to follow property chains like x.AssigneeGroup.Name, you have to make an alias to tell it that AssigneeGroup is a referenced entity. But NH has this information, it's right there in the mapping, so it's a shame you have to do this by hand.

Comment: I know what you are talking about. I was missing it also... (if this is a part of the "x.y.z" chain... why NHibernate does not create the association? I agree.. ;) But that is how NHibernate works right now... r

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the two tables if you wish to select columns from something other than the root table/entity (`Task` in our case).

Here is an example:

```
IQueryOver<Cat,Kitten> catQuery =
    session.QueryOver<Cat>()
        .JoinQueryOver<Kitten>(c => c.Kittens)
            .Where(k => k.Name == "Tiddles");
```

or

```
Cat catAlias = null;
Kitten kittenAlias = null;

IQueryOver<Cat,Cat> catQuery =
    session.QueryOver<Cat>(() => catAlias)
        .JoinAlias(() => catAlias.Kittens, () => kittenAlias)
        .Where(() => catAlias.Age > 5)
        .And(() => kittenAlias.Name == "Tiddles");
```

Alternatively you could use the nhibernate linq provider (nh > 3.0):

```
var q = ses.Query<Task>()
           .Select(x => new 
           { 
               Id = x.Id, 
               CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate, 
               Name = x.AssigneeGroup.Name, 
               IsProcessGroup = x.AssigneeGroup.IsProcessGroup
           });
```